# Can you help me to explain this code [ASM]

Tags: assembly, x86

I have a piece of small code and I can't understand what line 3 does. Can anyone help me to explain it. Many thanks.

```
mov     ebx, pointer1   //Assign of pointer pointer1 value to ebx
movzx   eax, byte ptr[esi]   //Get value from pointer address esi and assign to eax
mov     dx, [ebx + eax * 2]  //??? Dont know what it does
mov     [edi], dx
```

As I guess, If `[ebx]` is a byte array, that line will take `array[eax_value]` and `array[eax_value+1]`?

Comment: See my answer, your guess is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ebx holds a pointer value to pointer1.  eax is used to offset into it.  You are taking the nth 16bit value from pointer1 where n is determined by the value read into eax.

Comment: +1 I saw your name and then avatar and immediately thought *Go home Pete, you're duck*

Comment: Thank you Pete for confirming my thought. But still a bit confuse to value inside []. Can you explain more about [ebx + eax * 2]. For example: ebx hold value P, eax hold value 100. So formula above will be [ P + 100 * 2]. Is it equal to [P + 200] that get the value at pointer P+200 or equal to [P+100] and [P+101] that get value at pointer P+100 and P+101. Thank you.

Comment: X86 is byte addressable, all that means is that each address points to one byte.  So if you have an array that starts at address X, the nth byte is at adddress X+n.  Hope this makes sense.  Here is a really good link: http://denniskubes.com/2012/08/17/basics-of-memory-addresses-in-c/

Comment: Also, if I understand your question in the comments, you want the 100th 16th bit value, which is going to be 200 bytes away, if that makes sense

Answer (score 3):

Pointer1 is a pointer to a `short int` (16 bits) array. `esi` is pointing to some byte value which is an index in the array.

So the pointer is loaded to `ebx`, then the index is loaded into `eax` and multiplied by 2 (because of the 16 bit data size) and added as an offset to the array pointer.
The value from the array is copied to wherever `edi` is pointing to.